# photoshop to flash size trim

Tags: image, flash, photoshop

I've imported many clips from photoshop into flash and animated them. they are still editable by photoshop though.
Now i realized that the clips are much larger size than i require on runtime. Which leads to my first question :-
Does their original size effect the performance, if i am scaling them half on the rumtime?
And, if it does is there anyway i can shorten the size originally, given that i've already animated them?

Right clicking the image to edit it with photoshop, that does not work because we cant change size there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably does affect performance, but how noticable it is depends on their size and on how many of them are being scaled at the same time. What you do with them during runtime could also affect this.

You can change the size in Photoshop, but it means you will have to enlarge the image again in Flash, since any transformations like scaling will remain after resizing the image in Photoshop.

Comment: i can change the size on runtime in flash, bt tell me the way to change the size from photoshop (it shldnt affect the animations i've already made)

Comment: Simply go to Photoshop, save your file again, go to your library, right click on one of the images, go to properties and then select import. You can then choose the resized image and have it replace the old image. However, any scaling done in Flash will have to be reversed/changed, because otherwise yur image will be too small.